# HttpListener - проверка состояния

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Могу ли я посмотреть состояние сетевого подключения? При отправке ответного сообщения (`listenerContext.Response.Close()`) выскакивает ошибка

> Сообщение об исключении    "Попытка выполнить операцию для несуществующего сетевого подключения"

Comment: используйте `try/catch`, выброс ошибки и говорит вам о том, что соединения нет.

Comment: при большом количестве запросов сервер виснет пока не вызовет все исключения( хотелось бы их обходить а не вызывать и обрабатывать

Comment: @Bulson есть ли возможность не вызывать ошибки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Могу ли я посмотреть состояние сетевого подключения?

Нет, вы не можете отследить тот момент, когда клиент перестал отвечать. Способ это сделать, это попытаться что-то послать клиенту и отловить исключение. Поэтому — `try/catch`

- [Detect client disconnect with HttpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329932/detect-client-disconnect-with-httplistener)

> есть ли возможность не вызывать ошибки?

Как говорит документация, то за эту возможность отвечает флаг [`IgnoreWriteExceptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httplistener.ignorewriteexceptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
HttpListener.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но подскажите, с точки зрения правильности кода, будет ли это хорошим решением? Или лучше все же их обрабатывать?

Comment: @Leonid здравый смысл подсказывает, что лучше на ошибки как-то рефлексировать в catch-блоке и закрывать соединение корректно (см Dispose()/Abort())

Comment: Да. Я так и сделал. Но при 10000 запросов сервер повисал пока не выбрасывал все 10к исключений, что очень тормозит всю работу.